# Python, invoke a process pool without blocking the event loop

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-asyncio, coroutine, event-loop

If I run the following code:

```
import asyncio
import time
import concurrent.futures

def cpu_bound(mul):
    for i in range(mul*10**8):
        i+=1
    print('result = ', i)
    return i

async def say_after(delay, what):
    print('sleeping async...')
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

# The run_in_pool function must not block the event loop
async def run_in_pool():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        result = executor.map(cpu_bound, [1, 1, 1])

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(0.1, 'hello'))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(run_in_pool())
    task3 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(0.1, 'world'))

    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    await task1
    await task2
    await task3
    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The output is:

```
started at 18:19:28
sleeping async...
result =  100000000
result =  100000000
result =  100000000
sleeping async...
hello
world
finished at 18:19:34
```

This shows that the event loop blocks until the cpu bound jobs (`task2`) finish and it continues afterwards with the `task3`.

If I run only one cpu bound job (the `run_in_pool` is the following one):

```
async def run_in_pool():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        result = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, cpu_bound, 1)
```

Then it seems that the event loop doesn't block since the output is:

```
started at 18:16:23
sleeping async...
sleeping async...
hello
world
result =  100000000
finished at 18:16:28
```

How can I run many cpu bound jobs (in `task2`) in a process pool without blocking the event loop?

Comment: Actually the correct question for this subject would be: How to emulate the executor.map() method in such a way that it can be awaited, so that it doesn't block the event loop.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you discovered, you need to use asyncio's own `run_in_executor` to wait for submitted tasks to finish without blocking the event loop. Asyncio doesn't provide the equivalent of `map`, but it's not hard to emulate it:

```
async def run_in_pool():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = [loop.run_in_executor(executor, cpu_bound, i)
                   for i in (1, 1, 1)]
        result = await asyncio.gather(*futures)
```

Comment: Thanks that is what I was looking for. Essentially you need to give control back to the event loop with an await statement in the run_in_pool coroutine.