# How can I run a function multiple times at once in parallel from within a asyncio loop - All attempts have been concurrent so far

Tags: python, websocket, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I am listening into a websocket, when data is received, each item within that packet is examined by a function. I need to get the function to run multiple times at once (in parallel) to speed up the time taken to process and react to the data provided.

For example:

```
data_packet = {"sales": [{"item": Cat, "price": 5}, {"item": Fish, "price": 2}, {"item": Dog, "price": 7}]}

@client.listen("saleFeed")
async def on_sale_feed(data):
    if data['eventType'] == 'listed':
        print("Data recieved")
        for i in range(len(data['sales'])):
            check_listing(data['sales'], i)

def check_listing(data, position):
    if data[i].price <= median_price:
        add_to_cart() --> this process causes a webscraper to add the item to the cart
```

--I need all the processes started by the for loop to run at the same time

The code processes the data and adds the item to the cart if conditions are met. Ideally if all items in the data packet meet the conditions, they should all be added to the cart at the same time. Running sequencially results in items that meet the conditions to be missed (bought by another user).

I have tried using Multiprocessing, but i have been told that using both asyncio and multiprocessing is a coding sin.

Not sure where else to start, did briefly look at awaits and run_in_executor, but no luck.

Any help is appreciated, happy to provide more details if this is all too vague

Comment: Concurrent is not the opposite of parallel, in case you mistakenly thought that; by "All attempts have been concurrent so far" it's not clear if you mean that it has been working so far, or not.

Comment: its also unclear what check_listing is doing ... many operations maybe locked by the gil or some other mechanism preventing concurrency (concurrency === at the same time... )

Comment: The documentation uses concurrent in a way that _does not mean running in parallel_, it can mean this when multi-processing, which does run in parallel. There is no reason why you couldn't use asyncio for your IO bound functions and have it start multiple processes for parallel execution. It's just normally faster not to bother.

Comment: @RandomDavis, I have amended the post, thank you for the feedback

Comment: I think this answers your question - it shows how to have a process pool driven by an async event loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53304695/python-invoke-a-process-pool-without-blocking-the-event-loop

Comment: It is okay to mix asyncio and multiprocessing - especially if the code to be run is not async. You can create a pool of processes (or threads), call `run_in_executor` to get a future object for each, then await those futures. The parent program asyncio loop will continue to execute and this awaited task will wake and run as needed.